# how to edit checkbox values in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Initially i am inserting multiple  ids through multiple checkboxes. Now i want to open that page again for edit but i want some of the checkbox checked based on id i have inserted priviously.

*$courses contains all the nodes which i need to desplay  and $checkedarray are the nodes which comes from database*[id which got inserted after submission].
here is the code to uderstand the work..

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('xxx list');    
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
$courses = array();
foreach($terms as $term) {
    if($term->parents[0]==0){           
        $courses[$term->tid] = $term->name."<br />";
    }
    else{
        $parents = taxonomy_get_parents($term->tid);            
        $parentsName = $parents[$term->parents[0]]->name.' / ';
        $courses[$term->tid] = $parentsName.$term->name."<br />";
    }

}

$form['addlicense']['categories'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Series'),
    '#options' => $courses,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('series-list')),
    '#required' => TRUE,     

);
```

$checkedarray = array(5,6,7,8,9,10);
Now i have list of node which need to be appered as checked checkboxes which is in $checkedarray array... any help whould be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried using the #default_value attribute and setting it to $checkdarray ?

Comment: i used  #default_value after posting the question and it worked for me...BTW Thanks for the answere @claudiu.